# How to deal with the error caused by using mqtt and aligned time series for Version 0.13.3 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: mqtt, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I use the mqtt protocol to send commands from the client of Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.3, and the time series of the server is aligned, then an error is reported: `Caused by: org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.metadata.AlignedTimeseriesException: timeseries under this device are aligned, please use aligned interface`. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mqtt protocol cannot execute aligned time series in Apache IoTDB. You can try other protocols (like REST API) in Apache IoTDB to do that.